# Diagonal cycles, Beilinson-Flach elements and p-adic L-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have been studying the Euler systems of Beilinson-Flach elements and diagonal cycles, and their associated p-adic L-functions. I will stick to ordinary Hida families and $GL_2$ (so all local signs at finite places are +1, and no division quaternion algebras arise).

For triples (F,G,H) of Hida families, one finds three different 3-variable p-adic L-functions, denoted $L_p^f(F,G,H)$, $L_p^g(F,G,H)$ and $L_p^h(F,G,H)$ in the literature (see the papers of Darmon-Rotger and Hsieh). There is a three-variable Euler system Delta(F,G,H) of diagonal cycles such that these three p-adic L-functions are recovered by applying the big regulator/logarithm of Perrin-Riou and pairing against the families of periods $\eta_F \otimes \omega_G \otimes \omega_H$, $\omega_F \otimes \eta_G \otimes \omega_H$, and $\omega_F \otimes \omega_G \otimes \eta_H$, respectively. This is a result that I’ve seen announced in lectures by Darmon and Rotger, although this is apparently still in progress.

For pairs (F,G) of Hida families, one finds at least two different 3-variable p-adic L-functions, denoted $L_p(F,G)$ and $L_p(G,F)$ in the literature (see cf. Dasgupta’s Inventiones paper). The order of F and G matters, and these two p-adic L-functions are different. They can be viewed as analogues of $L_p^f(F,G,H)$, $L_p^g(F,G,H)$ above, where H is taken to be a Hida family of Eisenstein series.

Similarly as before, there is a three-variable Euler system BG(F,G,s) of Beilinson-Flach elements such that these two p-adic L-functions are recovered by applying the big regulator/logarithm of Perrin-Riou and pairing against the families of periods $\eta_F \otimes \omega_G$ and $\omega_F \otimes \eta_G$, respectively. This is a result of Kings, Loeffler, Zerbes.

My question is: in this latter setting, does there exist a third p-adic L-function, associated to BG(F,G,s) and the family of periods $\omega_F \otimes \omega_G$? It should be the analogue of $L_p^h(F,G,H)$. Has this putative p-adic L-function been introduced or studied anywhere? Does it have critical points, does it admit a characterization in terms of interpolation of classical L-values divided by suitable periods?